# Only 64 pictures are being sent to the server

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to upload pictures to server using basic HTML system and PHP (enctype="multipart/form-data").
So, everything works fine until I try to send more than 64 pictures. Only the first 64 are uploaded and other ones are being ignored.
I don't have any condition that limits the maximum amount of pictures to send or accept in my code and just don't know how to skip that.

I've changed a few values in php.ini regarding file sending but that didn't resolve the issue.

What could cause this uploading limit?

Comment: if you change the order of the images, can you upload more/less ?

Comment: No, always first 64 no matter about their order goes to the server.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to form any kind of answer... what are the 64 files? Does the total filesize exceed the maximum upload sizes defined in php.ini? Have you rebooted the server after making changes in php.ini? What errors are you getting? What debugging have you done?

Comment: can you check your upload_max_filesize & post_max_size check using echo phpinfo();die();

Comment: Can you show your upload code and accept code, and also the file sizes of the images you're sending. Just for reference, if you upload 64 high res images of 5mb each you have roughly 320 mb of data. That would hit some caps.

Comment: Okay, i've try to increase php.ini values even more. Maybe it would helps.